# Where does apps like google Search ads 360 or google analytics 360 actually store all its data?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I am writing google API's in python to request reports from Search Ads 360 or doubleclick.

My requests are not going through. Because My server sits behind a firewall and I need to tell my admin as to what all rules should be relaxed so that I can make these requests.

For this I need to know on what server or domain does google store this data. Is it google.cloud.com ?

Comment: Which exact API are you using? The documentation for that API should list its endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test your API request in [Google API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/)

If you apply URL whitelisting, whitelist the following URLs:

- accounts.google.com
- cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
- www.googleapis.com
- iam.googleapis.com
- storage.googleapis.com

For example [DoubleClick Search API v2](https://developers.google.com/search-ads/v2/reference/) request is using URL: https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclicksearch/v2/...

[oAuth authentication for API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#sendauthrequest) request is using: https://accounts.google.com/...